# How does one use $.deferred properly with non-observable functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

Let's say for example that I have two functions with random code inside and also that based on the user's system (slow, medium, or fast) there is no way to tell how long the two functions will take to complete, so the use of `setTimeout` is not practical when trying to fire `function2` only *after* `function1` is complete.

How can you use `jQuery.deferred` to make `function2` fire *only after* `function1` no matter what the time requirements are, and considering that both functions are 100% non-jQuery functions with no jQuery code inside them and therefore completely un-observable by jQuery? At the very most, the functions might include jQuery methods like `.css()` which do not have a time association and can run slower on old computers.

How do I assure that `function2` is not executing at the same time as `function1` if I call them like this:

```
function1(); function2();
```

using `$.deferred`? Any other answers besides those regarding `$.deferred` are also welcome!

**ADDED March 20:**
What if function1() is a lambda function where, depending on user input, the function may or may not have asynchronous calls and it is not possible to tell how many operations the function will do? It'd be a function where you wouldn't have any clue as to what would happen next, but no matter what, you'd still want function2 to execute only *after* everything from the lambda function (function1) is done, no matter how long it takes but as long as the asynchronous aspects are completed. How can this be achieved?

**ADDED March 22:**
So I guess the only way to do what I'm asking is to pass anonymous functions as callbacks to asynchromous functions that execute the callbacks after they are done, or to create event listeners that will do execute what you want when the event is finally triggered.

There's not really any way to just execute to asynchronous calls on two seperate lines and have them fire in order without manually constructing mechanisms (event handlers) within the frame containing the said functions to handle the actual execution of their actions.

A good example of these types of mechanisms would be jQuery's `.queue()` method and `$.Defferred` object.

The answers below along with reading up on jQuery's API on `.queue()`ing and using `$.Deferred` helped clarify this.

Tgr gave a great example below on how to create custom chainable functions using jQuery's `$.Deferred` object, and the custom functions themselves don't necessarily have to have any jQuery code inside them, which is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
function first(deferred) {
    // do stuff
    deferred.resolve();
}
function second() {
    // do stuff
}

$.Deferred(first).then(second);
```

But as Tomalak pointed out, this is unnecessary, unless you do something very tricky in `first` (like utilising web workers).

**Update**:

The basic idea is that whenever you do something that is not immediate, you create a Deferred object, and return that. (jQuery's AJAX calls already do this.) You can then use Deferred.then to delay follow-up operations.

```
function first() {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    var callback = function() {
        deferred.resolve();
    }
    // do immediate stuff
    someAsyncOperation(callback);
    return deferred.promise(); // turns the Deferred into a Promise, which
                               // means that resolve() will not be accessible
}

function second() {
    // do stuff
}

first().then(second); // or: $.when(first).then(second)
```

If `second` is also an asynchronous operation, you can use `$.when`'s merging capabilities:

```
function second() {
    var anotherDeferred = $.Deferred();
    // do stuff with anotherDeferred
    return anotherDeferred.promise();
}

$.when(first(), second()).then(third); // third will run at the moment when 
                                   // both first and second are done
```

Comment: Plus `deferred.resolve()` is nothing but a nice way of saying `if (typeof callback === "function") { callback() };`

Comment: If you run asynchronous functions where you have `//do stuff` the second function will start before the first function actually ends. What if i have the new scenerio i just updated?

Comment: @trusktr: see updated answer. If you make all your non-immediate functions return a promise, chaining them becomes simple. (Note that the jQuery documentation says that they follow the [CommonJS Promise/A proposal](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Promises/A), according to which you could simply chain callbacks returning promises like `$.when().then(first).then(second).then(third)`, but they do not seem to actually follow it.)

Comment: Hmmmm. Looks promising (no pun intended hehe).... Ahaa! i see!... so basically the promise is an event that triggers the desired function in the chained `.then()` method! And from what I can tell by looking at the code, the promise event specification is returned at the same time as `someAsyncOperation()` begins, but the event itself is triggered when `someAsyncOperation()` finally completes, right?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the detailed update. Really appreciate it! I'mma go have a go at it and return with the results.

Answer (score 5):

JavaScript itself is *not* asynchronous. It is single-threaded, synchronous.

```
function1();
function2();
```

will execute one after another unless they *contain* asynchronous calls. In that case, there will always be a callback you can pass (like `onSuccess` for XmlHttpRequest). Place the second function there.

To say the truth, they strictly execute one after another *even if* they contain asynchronous bits. It's just that the asynchronous bits might not yet be finished when the rest of the function is.

---

EDIT [Your jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/trusktr/9vRSG/), fixed ([see it](http://jsfiddle.net/9vRSG/3/)):

```
function foo() {
  $('#foo')
  .html('<span>foo1</span>')
  .animate(
    {              /* properties */
      left: '100px' 
    },      
    360,           /* duration */
    'swing',       /* easing */
    function () {  /* "complete" callback */
      $('#foo').append('<span>foo2</span>');
      bar();
    } 
  );
}
```

As I said. There will always be a callback you can pass.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I already knew about passing functions like that though. I'm looking for something more customized, in case the contents of my functions have nothing to do with jQuery.

Comment: @trusktr: I'm not really sure what "more customized" means. The functions you pass do not *have to* have anything to do with jQuery, any JS function object will work. And since you provided a jQuery example, what else was there for me to work with?

Comment: So basically, if I were to use setTimeout() in function1 for 5 seconds, then the only way to make function2 execute after 5 seconds is either to pass it into the setTimeout() function or create an event that gets triggered when setTimeout() finishes and where this event can trigger function2, right?

I'm guess I'm just learning all this real time awesomeness. :D But you're right, my question wasn't as detailed as it could have been because i didn't know what to ask for exactly.

Comment: @tuskr: Yes, the only way to make function2 execute after 5 seconds is to attach it to function1 (if function1 itself is strictly synchronous) or register it as a callback for an event. Abstractions like `$.Deferred().then()` are just semantic sugar around this basic behavior. And even though they are more expressive, this is what they actually boil down to.